# SharePoint Online - reindex list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powershell, microsoft-graph

I would need to manually call re-index for a SP List in SP Online like once/twice a day.

Is there any PowerShell/ MS Graph solution for this?

This list is having a lot of items on it that are being deleted / created on daily basis and I need search to be working with current items and not point to the old deleted ones.

I need to implement that into a code. Solution of clicking the button in advanced settings is not desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the PnP PowerShell to re-index a SharePoint Online list or library

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://crescenttech.sharepoint.com"
$ListName="Projects"

#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)

#Request Reindex
Request-PnPReIndexList -Identity $ListName
```

**Reference**: [SharePoint Online: How to Reindex a List or Document Library using PowerShell?](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/04/sharepoint-online-reindex-list-document-library-using-powershell.html)

Comment: awesome, thanks, will try to implement that to my project in C#. By the way, aren't you aware if there is something similar in MS Graph?

Comment: Not exactly. I am not sure if this is even possible using MS Graph.

Comment: Sorry for late response, I have added a PS script to my MS Graph solution and once it is done I just run the script to reindex. thanks